# Should you edit/delete the default apache site config?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, virtualhost, namevirtualhost

I've just followed [this tutorial](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/01/09/setting-up-name-based-virtual-hosting/) on setting up name-based virtulization in Apache, and it worked really well.

The tutorial basically got you to add a config file to `sites-available` called `yourdomain.com`, and then link it to `sites-enabled`.

By default, apache includes two site config files in `sites-available`, `default` and `defualt-ssl`.

Should you edit these files or remove the link form the `sites-enabled` directory?

After playing around with this (locally), I realised that by default the default site points to your root `/var/www` directory, and so if someone goes to the IP of your server directly, could they not then see all the vhosts and other directories in `/var/www`, unless the default vhost config is changed to point to a different directory, or remvoed from `sites-enabled`?

I'm just wondering what is commonly done with the default site if the server is being used for name-based virtualization?

Sorry if I got some of this incorrect as I'm quite new to running my own web server.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just disable them if you're not using them

```
a2dissite default
a2dissite default-ssl
apachectl graceful
```

This simply removes the link to sites-enabled, so they're not included in the config anymore

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the default files which is equivalent to removing the link from sites-enabled directory.

```
a2dissite default
```

If you don't want to disable default site but want to hide the directories then you can put up a home page (index.html) in `/var/www/` or [hide](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/26/apache-tips-tricks-disable-directory-indexes/) the directory indexes.